# C# dropped UDP packets on newly created socket

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Hey all.  I'm having an issue with c# and it quite possibly may be the debugger but I'm fairly new to c# (not new to c/c++)

There's code below.  Here is the issue I'm having.

I get UDP, not guaranteed delivery, sure. I expect that the occasional packet is dropped on the network or by windows if I'm stuffing the pipe full.  However, the problem I am having is that after I create a new socket, I try and send a packet with 1 byte of data.  This packet is dropped.  I can try and send it twice, it's dropped both times.  However, if I send 1k worth of data, it goes through.  If I create another socket (by clicking the button again), everything works fine.  Now here's the weird thing.  If I stop and restart debugging the project without making any changes to the source, all my packets get sent without problems.  It only seems to happen the on the first run after the project is built.  Anyway, here's the code to reproduce the issue.  After a few hours of searching and reading I'm at a loss.
edit: Wanted to clarify that I'm using wireshark and can see that the packets are dropped.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] a = new byte[1] {0x00};
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
            b[i] = 0xFF;
        }

        IPEndPoint _ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.200.202"),5546);
        Socket _server =  new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        _server.SendTo(a, 1, SocketFlags.None, _ipep);
        _server.SendTo(a, 1, SocketFlags.None, _ipep);
        _server.SendTo(b, 1024, SocketFlags.None, _ipep);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the receiving code?

Comment: I don't see the relevance to posting the receiving code.  It is written in c on an arm processor.  I can see everything with wireshark.

Comment: The code I've posted above will allow you to recreate the problem if your so inclined.

Comment: I wonder if you'd lose the packets if you made the a into a word instead of a byte. wild guessing again but can this thread be some help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655332/udp-packets-are-dropped-when-its-size-is-less-than-12-byte-in-a-certain-pc-how-d/4655581#4655581

or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576184/net-sockets-buffer-overflow-no-error/2576556#2576556

Comment: @detay I saw one of those two posts.  Thank you for them.  I don't know if a word vs byte would make a difference but I do want to mention that all three sendto calls return the correct number of bytes sent regardless of if they show up on the wire.

Comment: so anyway, I've found now that the packets are only dropped after an ARP request is made to the endpoint.  In the .000146 seconds it takes to for the endpoint to reply, two udp packets are dropped.  Is there a way to test when the socket is ready to send?

Comment: @Jason: I asked you about the receiving code because from your post it isn't obvious that packets are LOST when SENDING.  Did you try Sleep()-ing for some time between the packets?  10ms, 100ms?

Comment: sorry, still not sure what the issue is but I've narrowed it down to the networking stack on windows.  when the first packet is sent, it initiates an arp request to resolve the mac address for the client.  This is only initiated by sending data, not creating the socket.  Because the udp packet cannot be sent immediately (waiting for arp reply) it is dropped.  Since the recommended timeout for arp table entries is 15 seconds, any pause in a udp datastream longer than that will force another arp request to be sent and additional packets dropped.  Could it be my nic and not the network stack?

Comment: I don't think that its the arp issue. Because as far as I know, once you receive arp response and client mac address is added to your ARP cache, your system shouldn't send the ARP again. So even if you modify the code or rebuild the code, it doesn't invalidate your system's ARP cache. You can write "arp -a" on command prompt to see your ARP cache. Anyways, the problem seems very strange.

Comment: Couple things Tayyab:  arp entries in windows expire after around 15 seconds of no communication between client and host.  Making the arp entry static fixes the problem however is far from ideal as a solution. True rebuilding the code will not invalidate the arp cache.  Instead, the 15 seconds between builds does :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment about ARP issue, I would like to suggest some ways to debug and narrow down the issue and then suggest some solutions.

**How to Debug:**

1. Try making the ARP entry "static" so
   that your PC do not send ARP request
   each time. To make ARP entry static
   you can write "arp" on command
   prompt to see the list of options
   and help to add static ARP entry.
2. Another idea is to open the command
   prompt and write "ping
   192.168.200.202 -t", so that your PC keeps on pinging the other client.
   This will keep your PC's ARP entry
   up to date and when you will run
   your C# program, it will not send
   ARP again, and it will directly send
   the UDP.

The above points are just to debug and ensure that you guessed the problem right.

**The Possible Solutions:**

1. If its the ARP issue, then I am almost sure that its problem with your network switch, so try replacing your "Switch" (I think its faulty).
2. If it is possible for you then you can think of making your "ARP Entry" static. This might not be a good idea for all the situations and totally depend if nature of your application allows to go for this approach.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  My application would be tolerant of using static arp entries.  In win7 you need to use netsh as this functionality has been removed from "arp".  The only packet that's not fault tolerant is the first packet.  I just send it twice with a pause between.  If both are sent, its not an issue.  However, i find it interesting that the first packet to a destination not in the arp cache has a high likelihood of being dropped.   Guess my definition of best effort differs.  Thanks for the tips.